# django forms exclude fields on init rather than in the meta class

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to exclude certain fields in the init function of a modelform depending on a parameter passed in, how do I do this?  I know I can add exclude fields using the meta class of a model form but I need this to be dynamic depending on the variable passed in.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can modify the `self.fields` list after calling `super`.

Comment: so what would i need to type.  for example if I wanted to remove the field 'name' from the modelform

Comment: `if 'name' in self.fields: del self.fields['name']`

Answer (score 4):

You should use modelform_factory to create the form on the fly and pass in the fields you want to exclude.

```
def django.forms.models.modelform_factory   (       
     model,
    form = ModelForm,
    fields = None,
    exclude = None,
    formfield_callback = lambda f: f.formfield()     
)
```

So something like

```
modelform_factory(MyModel, MyModelForm, exclude=('name',))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `self._meta` instead of `self.Meta`, because the `ModelForm.__new__` method get attributes form `self.Meta` and puts them into `self._meta`.

Answer (score 1):

Related, to exclude fields from a sub-class, I have extended the ModelForm class like so:

```
 class ModelForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

     meta = getattr(self, 'Meta', None)
     exclude = getattr(meta, 'exclude', [])

     for field_name in exclude:
       if field_name in self.fields:
         del self.fields[field_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

I made like this:

```
class Meta:
    exclude = [field.label for field in Fields.objects.filter(visible=False)] + ['language', 'created_at']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to note: if your form is called from a ModelAdmin class, just create a get_form method for the ModelAdmin:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    exclude = ()

    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        exclude += ('field1',)

    if obj:
        exclude += ('field2',)

    self.exclude = exclude
    return super(ProfessorAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

PS: change ProfessorAdmin by the method "owner" class.